# Указание первоначального адреса элемента

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net, turbopascal

Был дан массив из 3-х разрядных чисел,необходимо было найти суммы цифр каждого числа и выстроить их по убыванию с указанием их первоначальных адресов. например,в начале было число 526 ,стоял на 5ом месте исходного массива, сумма его цифр 13, он получился самым большим в новом массиве,но мы должны указать его начальное место,то есть "был на 5ом месте исходного массива".

```
program lab;
    const n=10;
    Type MyType=record
       number:integer;
       indexPrev:byte;
    end;
    Type ArrMyType = array[1..n] of MyType;
    var
     i,j: integer;
     a:array[1..n] of MyType;

    function f(x:integer):integer;
    var
      d,s: integer;
    begin
      s:=0;
      while x > 0 do
       begin
        d:= x mod 10;
        s:= s + d;
        x:= x div 10;
       end;
       f:=s;
    end;

    procedure swap(var x,y: integer);
       var t: integer;
     begin
        t := x;
        x := y;
        y := t
     end; 


    begin
    writeln('Исходный массив');
    for i:=1 to n do
      begin
        a[i].number:=random(100)+500;
        a[i].indexPrev:=i; 
        write(i,' эл. = ',a[i].number,' ');
      end;
    writeln;
    writeln('Cумма цифр в числе,без сортировки');  
    for i:=1 to n do
     a[i].number := f(a[i].number);
    for i:=1 to n do
      write(' y ',i,' эл. = ',a[i].number, ' ');
    for i:=1 to n-1 do
     for j:=i+1 to n do
      if a[i].number < a[j].number then
       swap(a[i].number,a[j].number); 
    writeln;   
    writeln('Новый массив');
    for i:=1 to n do
   write(a[i],' ','начальный номер = ') //????????????????????????
    end.
```

И как вывести начальное место?

Comment: Тот, кто писал этот код, несомненно, должен понимать, где взять первоначальное место ;) Процедуру `swap` нужно изменить, чтоб она обменивала не целые числа, а записи `MyType` целиком

Comment: `write(a[i].number,' ','начальный номер = ', a[i].indexPrev);`

Answer (score 0):

```
program sort;
const
  N = 10;

type
  Number = record
    Value: integer;
    Sum:   integer;
    Index: integer;
  end;

  ArrayOfNumber = array [1..N] of Number;

function SumOfDigits(num: integer): integer;
var
  sum: integer;
begin
  sum := 0;

  while (num > 0) do
  begin
    Inc(sum, num Mod 10);
    num := num Div 10;
  end;

  result := sum;
end;

procedure BubbleSort(var numbers: ArrayOfNumber);
var
  i, j: integer;
  tmp: Number;
begin
  for i := N - 1 downto 1 do
  begin
    for j := N - i downto 1 do
    begin
      if numbers[j].Sum < numbers[j + 1].Sum then 
      begin
          tmp := numbers[j];
          numbers[j] := numbers[j + 1];
          numbers[j + 1] := tmp
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

var
  numbers: ArrayOfNumber;
  i: integer;

begin
  Write('Исходный массив:');

  Randomize;

  for i := 1 to N do
  begin
    with numbers[i] do
    begin
      Value := Random(100, 999);
      Sum := SumOfDigits(Value);
      Index := i;
      Write(Value:4);
    end;
  end;

  WriteLn();
  WriteLn('Результат:');

  BubbleSort(numbers);

  for i := 1 to N do
  begin
    with numbers[i] do
    begin
      WriteLn(Value:4, ', SUM:', Sum:3, ', OLD:', Index:3);
    end;
  end;
end.
```

**Вывод**:

```
Исходный массив: 914 232 252 591 724 588 129 404 121 480
Результат:
 588, SUM: 21, OLD:  6
 591, SUM: 15, OLD:  4
 914, SUM: 14, OLD:  1
 724, SUM: 13, OLD:  5
 129, SUM: 12, OLD:  7
 480, SUM: 12, OLD: 10
 252, SUM:  9, OLD:  3
 404, SUM:  8, OLD:  8
 232, SUM:  7, OLD:  2
 121, SUM:  4, OLD:  9
```